# Can't able to make mouse hover clickable on an element in Odoo

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, odoo

I have used following code by mouse hover event

```
cash=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//Select[@name='journal_id']/option[normalize-space(text())='Cash (EUR)']")
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
Hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(cash)
Hover.click().build().perform()
```

For this I have imported library called

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

But it is giving runtime error called :

```
ERROR: test_start (__main__.Saletest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sale_test.py", line 106, in test_start
    Hover.click().build().perform()
AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'build'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so what is the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't build - only perform. Replace:

```
Hover.click().build().perform()
```

with:

```
Hover.click().perform()
```